# HTML signature on macosx font

Tags: html, css, fonts, signature

I have macosx and I made a html signature for mail.app but when I send email and someone pick it with windows property font-family does not work.

When I send from MAC to MAC everything is okey.

Here are my styles:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansitalic';
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansitalic';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('woff'),
    url('opensans-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanssemibold';
    src: url('opensans-semibold-webfont.eot');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanssemibold';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('woff'),
    url('opensans-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanslight';
    src: url('opensans-light-webfont.eot');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanslight';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('woff'),
    url('opensans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

And also this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give absolute url

```
url('opensans-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

src: url('opensans-semibold-webfont.eot');
```

Note1: Maybe it´s a good ideia to put the fonts in a remote server or use CDN

Note2: It only works on Apple Mail and iPhone

Comment: There are full url but I didnt paste it here because they are sol LONG i pased it here url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('woff'), in dotted place

Comment: Font face only works on Mac mail and iphone - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3044/does-font-face-work-in-email

Comment: is there any way to replace it?

Comment: Make a fallback on all font-face - example:  @font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansitalic', arial, verdana;
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot');
}

Comment: It will be opensans OR arial OR veranda. Am I right?